# Initialize string in Ada with null characters

Tags: ada, gnat

I am new to Ada,
I need to make initialize a string with null characters, how can I do it?
So far I can initialize a string with spaces as follows:

```
user_str : String(1..50) := (others => ' ');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
user_str : String(1..50) := (others => Character'Val(0));
```

or

```
user_str : String(1..50) := (others => Ada.Characters.Latin_1.NUL);
```

Unlike some other languages, Ada does not have a special syntax for embedding speclal characters in character or string literals (like C's `'\0'`, for example).

(Of course the latter requires an appropriate `with` clause.)

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
user_str : String(1..50) := (others => ascii.nul);
```